# Check if all content of arrays are between a range of numbers, without duplicates

Tags: arrays, comparison

I need a way to see if all the numbers entered by the user are make up the numbers from 1 to 15. Wihout duplicates.

What I have so far is a program that will check if the numbers are over 15, or less then 1, but I don't have any idea of how to check every number entered into the array, and see if it's already been inputted into the array.

This is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    bool somethingBadHappend=false;         //booleans like this make it easy for the program to be read
    int numbers[15]{};
    cout << "enter 15 numbers:";
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        cin>>numbers[i];                    //entering them into the array
    }

 
        if (numbers[i] > 15|| numbers[i]<=0)
        {
            somethingBadHappend = true;
        }
    }

    if (somethingBadHappend)      //see the perfect use of code here?
    {
        cout<<"NOT GOOD";           // How elegant!
    }
    else
        cout<<"GOOD";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question, you have to do another check into array to see the duplicate.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    bool somethingBadHappend=false;         //booleans like this make it easy for the program to be read
    int numbers[15]{};
    
    cout << "enter 15 numbers:";
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        cin>>numbers[i];                    //entering them into the array
    }

//to find values >15 or <1
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] > 15 || numbers[i]<=0)
        {
            somethingBadHappend = true;
        }
    }
//to find the duplicate into array
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                for(int c=0; c<15; c++){
                    if(i!=c){ // check the different index
                        if(numbers[i]==numbers[c]){
                            somethingBadHappend = true; //found duplicate
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    if (somethingBadHappend)      //see the perfect use of code here?
    {
        cout<<"NOT GOOD";           // How elegant!
    }
    else
        cout<<"GOOD";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the delay